# How to call WCF Data Service that returns bool Getting "Cannot include key predicates or empty parenthesis."

Tags: wcf, odata

I have a WCF with the following signature:

```
    [WebGet]
    public bool UserHasRoles(string UserName, string ApplicationName)
    {
        if (SecurityCheck())
        {
            UserRightsApplicationEntities context = new UserRightsApplicationEntities();
            return context.UserRolesAndFunctions.Where(urf => urf.LogonName == UserName && urf.ApplicationName == ApplicationName).Count() > 0;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I can compile and run the service, but when I call it I get the error; "The request URI is not valid. The segment 'UserHasRoles' cannot include key predicates or empty parenthesis".

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the calling code:

```
    public static bool UserHasRoles(string applicationName, string userName)
    {
        DataServiceQuery<bool> q = GetApplicationServicesDataContext()
            .CreateQuery<bool>(Constants.ServiceOperations.UserHasRoles)
            .AddQueryOption(Constants.ClassProperties.Application.ApplicationName, string.Format("'{0}'", applicationName))
            .AddQueryOption(Constants.ClassProperties.User.UserName, string.Format("'{0}'", userName));

        bool userHasRoles = q.Execute().FirstOrDefault();
        return userHasRoles;
    }
```

Here's the web call:

`"http://svr-webdev1:8081/UserRightsApplicationService.svc/UserHasRoles()?ApplicationName='User Rights Management'&UserName='domain\username'"`

And what's interesting is that if I remove the parenthesis from UserHasRoles such as:

`"http://svr-webdev1:8081/UserRightsApplicationService.svc/UserHasRoles?ApplicationName='User Rights Management'&UserName='domain\username'"`

It works correctly.

Ok, so I tried a different approach that seems to work, but not really sure why:

```
    public static bool DoesUserHaveRoles(string applicationName, string userName)
    {
        string queryString = string.Format("UserHasRoles?ApplicationName='{0}'&UserName='{1}'", applicationName, userName);

        bool doesUserHaveRoles = (GetApplicationServicesDataContext().Execute<bool>(new Uri(queryString, UriKind.Relative))).FirstOrDefault();
        return doesUserHaveRoles;
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling the web service?  please include specific javascript

Comment: Please post your calling method, we can't help if we don't have the code that's causing the error